# Check for DBEmpty like DBNull in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table `Employee` having a column `JoiningDate` of type **DateTime**.

I am fetching this value in asp.net.

I know to **check DBnull** we use `dr["JoiningDate"] != DBNull.Value` .

But if this `JoiningDate` is empty like `''`, which fetching it is making it like `1/1/1900`.

What is the best way to check **DB EMPTY in asp.net** for a datetime column.

## Details :

JoiningDate is a DateTime field..I made it empty string in stead of NULL..

And while fetching this in asp.net `in dr["JoiningDate"] which is a datarow`, it gave `1/1/1900`.

## Code Example

```
DataSet dsEmployee = null;
dsEmployee = Data.Select("SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID = '" + _id + "'");

DataRow drEmployee = dsEmployee.Tables[0].Rows[0];

if(drEmployee["JoiningDate"] != string.Empty)
{

}
```

Comment: What is the type of this column?

Comment: @JonSkeet it is DateTime.

Comment: You need a bit more detail in your question. What SQL server? What data types are the SQL column and the C# variable? Some additional sample code (for context) would be nice, too.

Comment: You could do something like `dr["JoiningDate"] != DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: It should really be `SqlDateTime.MinValue` I think, not sure if I am right.

Comment: If it's really DateTime it can't be empty string, it's probably varchar and you're just using it as DateTime in your code. Personally I check those thing like this: `if ((dr["JoiningDate"] + "").Length > 0) { ... }` since adding empty string automagically converts to string.

Comment: @Tim DateTime Min value is `1/1/0001`

Comment: @V4Vendetta - You're right.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: How is it automatically fetching it as `1/1/1900`, Can you show the select i guess somwething there is doing the transform or is it the default value for that column ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta I think the column is `datetime` and the OP is _inserting_ '' into the column which is implicity cast to 1/1/1900.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez .. You are correct .. I was trying to make sure the check should work for all cases..So is there a way to check this emptiness.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr["JoiningDate"])))
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(........))
{

......

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this to check...

```
 if(  dr["JoiningDate"] != DBNull.Value && (DateTime)dr["JoiningDate"] != DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900")) {
//do...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your check like this

```
if(dr["JoiningDate"] != DBNull.Value && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr["JoiningDate"])))
{
     //Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say `dr["JoiningDate"]` is not returning `null` then

- you are changing the value in the `SELECT` query
- The default value of the column is set to `1/1/1900`

Also please check where you insert the records in that case you would be passing `null` for that particular column so that it assumes the default value which is being returned

So you should rely on checking the condition by making a `DateTime` instance like `new DateTime(1900,1,1)` and then compare